# Mongo Connector Not Running to Create Index in Apache Solr

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, solr, lucene

I am trying to index data stored inside a Mongo DB collection. I am following the below link to do that:

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/nosql/b/weblog/archive/2017/02/03/indexing-mongodb-data-in-apache-solr

But when I am starting the mongo-connector using this command it is saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mongo-connector", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 104, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1275, in main
    conf.parse_args()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/config.py", line 106, in parse_args
    + ', '.join(args))
mongo_connector.errors.InvalidConfiguration: The following command line arguments are not recognized: –n, database1.collection1
```

**Command:**

```
root@workstation:/var/lib/mongodb# mongo-connector --unique-key=_id  -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/wlslog -d solr_doc_manager –n database1.collection1
```

If `-n` is invalid then what should I use to point the database? I have searhed in net but could not get anything useful. Can anyone help? I am new to Solr. Can this happen due to version incompatibility of python/mongoDB/mongoConnector/Solr?

Comment: did you find solution to it

Comment: I am running the solr war in tomcat & indexing data using the update API. The update REST API is a POST call & you can send data in json or xml format. See my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421746/setting-up-apache-solr-in-cloud-mode/51444770#51444770

Answer (score 0):

Your command is invalid: `–n database1.collection1`. Use '-n' instead of '–n'.