# Setting Up Apache Solr in Cloud Mode

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solr4

I have to do the following:

1. I have to deploy Solr on 2 servers/nodes.
2. Deploy Zookeeper on another server.
3. Upload a custom config to Zookeeper
4. Create a custom collection with 2 shards and 2 replicas

**Version of Solr 7.4.0 & Zookeeper:** 3.4.12

I have done the following:

**Set Up Zookeeper:**

- Created a Zookeeper data folder & made a zoo.conf & put the dataDir there.
- Started zookeeper using `./zkServer.sh start`

**Set up Solr:**

- Started Solr using:

  `./solr start -cloud -s /home/demo/LocalFolder/Downloads/SolrHome -p 8987 -z localhost:2181`
- Trying to upload config in Zookeeper using:
  `./solr create -c mycollection -d /media/sf_VM/Dump/conf`

It is giving me an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    ... 17 more
</pre>
```

I have searched many pages & seen Solr tutorials but there they have used the default examples. I just dont have any step by step idea to

1. How to Upload a config in Zookeeper?
2. Then what I need to do to create a collection pointing to that config. I want that collection to have 2 shards & 2 replicas.
3. Where will be the solr.xml. If it should be in Zookeeper how do I upload it there
4. How do I see in Zookeeper that the config has been uploaded?

I know this question might be a duplicate. I have read several of posts but not able to come up a solution. Please help.

Comment: There should be more information attached to your stack trace. That stack trace is just the part saying "something went wrong", while missing the part that says exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured out how to setup. Please note that I have read these steps from different site & gathered here step by step:

## 1. Set Up ZooKeeper:

This is used to keep the collection specific configuration files to store in a central space & map it with a name. Later we can use this name to create collection which would point to this config. This config is the same as you find in the below folder:
`solr-7.4.0\server\solr\configsets\sample_techproducts_configs\conf`

1.1 Download latest Zookeeper. I have used 3.4.12

1.2 Unpack downloaded archive and copy conf/zoo_sample.cfg to conf/zoo.cfg

1.3 Modify zoo.cfg:

1.3.1 Change dataDir to directory where you want to hold all cluster configuration data.
`dataDir=/var/zookeeper/data`

1.3.2 Add information about all Zookeeper servers: I have used only 1 ZooKeeper server so this is not required. If you want to add more servers then please go through the below links:

[DZone Tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/solrcloud-howto)

[Apache Tutorial](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble)

1.3.3 Start ZooKeeper using (after going to zookeeper-3.4.12/):

`./bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground conf/zoo.cfg`

OR

`./bin/zkServer.sh start conf/zoo.cfg`

**Note:** You can stop the ZooKeeper using the below command:

`bin/zkServer.sh stop`

1.3.4 ZooKeeper Status:

Hit the below:

`bin/zkServer.sh status`

Or do `telnet localhost 2181` and hit `stats` when connected.

## 2. Set Up Solr

2.1 Download the Solr

2.2 Extract install_solr_service.sh from the .tar file. Solr includes a service installation script (bin/install_solr_service.sh) to help you install Solr as a service on Linux. For more info [click here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/taking-solr-to-production.html).

`tar -xzf solr-7.4.0.tgz solr-7.4.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2`

2.3 Install Solr as a service using the above script:

`sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-7.4.0.tgz`

This will also extracting solr-7.4.0.tgz to `/opt/solr`

2.4 Go to `/opt/solr` and do the following:

`mkdir solr/server/solr2
mkdir solr/server/solr3
mkdir solr/server/solr4`

`cp solr/server/solr/solr.xml solr/server/solr2
 cp solr/server/solr/solr.xml solr/server/solr3
 cp solr/server/solr/solr.xml solr/server/solr4`

2.5 Change the jetty port in solr.xml. Do this for all the 3 solr.xml mentioned in the above step:

`vi solr/server/solr2/solr.xml`

Search for the port 8983 & change it 8984 (for solr2), change it 8985 (for solr3), change it 8986 (for solr4)

2.6 Stop the Solr running at 8983

`root@dev-base:/opt/solr/bin# ./solr stop  -p  8983`

2.7 Start all the solr instances:

`root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr start -c -s  server/solr -p 8983 -z  localhost:2181 -noprompt -force
root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr start -c -s  server/solr2 -p 8984 -z  localhost:2181 -noprompt -force
root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr start -c -s  server/solr3 -p 8985 -z  localhost:2181 -noprompt -force
root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr start -c -s  server/solr4 -p 8986 -z  localhost:2181 -noprompt -force`

**Note: Running solr as a root is not recommended for security reason.**

2.8 See Solr Status:

`root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr status`

## 3 Make a Custom Config

3.1 Copy the `conf` directory from `solr-7.4.0\server\solr\configsets\sample_techproducts_configs\conf` to another location `(In my case it is /media/sf_VM/Dump/new/conf )`.

3.2 Change the `managed-schema` file inside `conf` to specify the fields you are using.

## 4 Upload the config to ZooKeeper:

`root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr zk -z localhost:2181 upconfig -d /media/sf_VM/Dump/new/conf -n myConf6`

The name of the config I have uploaded is `myConf6`

## 5 Create a Solr Collection using this custom config

`root@dev-base:/opt/solr# bin/solr create -c myNewCollection -n myConf6 -shards 2 -replicationFactor 2 -force`

Hit [Solr Admin URL](http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cloud)

## 6 Index Data Using POST API using Json

URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/myNewCollection/update

Method: POST

Body:

```
[{
    "_id": "99999999999999999999",
    "author": [
        "New Inserted 9000"
    ],
    "authorLastName": [
        "New Inserted 9000"
    ],
    "impn": "New Inserted 9000",
    "isbn10": "9999999999",
    "isbn13": "9999999999999",
    "title": "New Inserted 9000",
    "publisher": "New Inserted 9000",
    "sales_a": 5.0,
    "sales_t": 5.0,
    "haveImage": 1,
    "pages": "76",
    "image": "http://ip.ip.com/is/image/",
    "format": "Paper",
    "mtc_id": "99999999999",
    "subjects" : [         
        "9000"
    ]
    "rating": 0,
    "description_long": "Snahashis call me in your marriage."
}
```

### Delete a configuration in Zookeeper:

If you want to delete an old/wrong configuration already uploaded to ZooKeeper run the below command:

`./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd clear -z "<ZK_HOST>:<ZK_PORT>" /configs/AAA`

The path of the configuration is `/configs/< name of the configset >`

**To delete a specific file:**

`zkcli.sh --zkhost <ZK_HOST>:<ZK_PORT> -cmd clear /configs/<MY_COLLECTION>/solrconfig.xml`

### Upload an updated file:

`zkcli.sh --zkhost <ZK_HOST>:<ZK_PORT> -cmd putfile /configs/<MY_COLLECTION>/solrconfig.xml  /<MY_UPDATED_FILE_LOCAL_FOLDER>/solrconfig.xml`

**Then we need to restart the solr nodes.**

### To Delete a Collection Via API:

1. First delete alias created on this collection (if any)

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETEALIAS&name=aliasName

2. Delete Collection:

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=collectionName